# laravel роутер по умолчанию в субдомене

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь сделать роутер по умолчанию на домене и суб домене, вот что пробую:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'home';
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'video.s1.loc'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'sub';
    });
});
```

В результате при переходе на s1.loc и video.s1.loc появляется "home", как сделать, что бы появлялся "sub" при переходе на video.s1.loc.  Если добавить /test в в sub route, то по переходу на video.s1.loc/test отображает "sub", а вот в корневую директорию не хочет работать, как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Роуты основного домена нужно объединить в группу аналогично суб домену.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 's1.loc'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'home';
    });
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'video.s1.loc'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'sub';
    });
});
```